# Getting ERROR 000539 running Raster Calculator in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

I am trying to run Raster Calculator in ModelBuilder, however I am getting what looks like two errors after my model reaches a certain step:

```
ERROR 000539: Error running
```

I'm not sure if it is a syntax issue or something else. Raster Calculator is used in earlier steps in the same model with no problem.

[image]

Below is what I wrote:

```
Con((("%TWI.TIF%">15) & ("%NDVI.TIF%"<-0.05)),1,Con(((10<="%TWI.TIF%"<=15) & (-0.075<="%NDVI.TIF%"<0.05)),2,3))
```

Could someone help with my syntax?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Have you reviewed the other four of these Q&As? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000539+modelbuilder+raster-calculator

Comment: I believe it is the second part of your CON statement, this `10<="%TWI.TIF%"<=15` and the other query are not correct syntax. What is it you are trying to ask? Is the tif  great than 10 and smaller than 15? If that is what you you were trying to ask then this syntax is incorrect.